# Getting null string from SQL database

Tags: nullpointerexception

I'm trying to pull data from sql database and assigning it to text boxes.
But I get error when there is no data in column (null).

```
 string athleteId = Request.Cookies["LoggedInUser"].ToString();
             var athlete = AthleteDAL.GetAthleteByID(athleteId);
             if (athlete.AthleteFName != null)
             {
                TextBoxFirstName.Text = athlete.AthleteFName.ToString();}
```

I'm getting null point exception on if statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to have this
if (athlete!=null && athlete.AthleteFName != null)

because athlete may be null and trying to use it (athlete.AthleteFName) is an invalid operation

Comment: Thanks, you solved my problem. I was getting null (athlete) from database because of some error in GetAthleteByID function. Now I fixed the function too. Thanks man!